# Django REST framework: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'books'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_restFramework/users/ , return text

> AttributeError at /app_restFramework/users/
>   'User' object has no attribute 'books'

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

serializers.py

```
from app_restFramework.models import Book,User
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    books = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many = True, read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'books')
```

views.py

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^app_restFramework/users/$', app_restFramework.views.UserList.as_view() ),
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have not specified the `related_name` in the `ManyToManyField`. By default it will be `book_set`. Therefore you can do:

```
book_set = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
```

If you want to use `books` in the serializers, you can do this in the `Book` model:

```
owner = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="books")
```